# in matlab how to plot 5 figures at the same time when i run without overlapping each others?

Tags: matlab, plot, geometry, figure

in matlab if i have this code

```
%// Set parameters
R = sqrt(10) ;  %// radius
C = [0 0]; %// center [x y]
N = 50;    %// number of points inside circle
%// generate circle boundary
t = linspace(0, 2*pi,100);
x = R*cos(t) + C(1);
y = R*sin(t) + C(2);
%// generate random points inside it
th = 2*pi*rand(N,1);
r  = R*rand(N,1);
xR = r.*cos(th) + C(1);
yR = r.*sin(th) + C(2);
%// Plot everything
figure(1), clf, hold on
plot(x,y,'b')
text(0,0,'C')
plot(xR,yR,'p')
axis equal
 radius=cell(4,1);
       radius {1,1}=1;
       radius {1,2}=0.5;
       radius {1,3}=3;
       radius {1,4}=2;
       for j=1:4
       for i=1:50
           theta=0:.01:2*pi;
           x=radius {1,j}*cos(theta)+rank1{i,2}(1);
            y=radius {1,j}*sin(theta)+rank1{i,2}(2);
             plot(x,y)
             hold on
       end
       end
```

how to plot 5 figures at the same time when i run without overlapping each others ?when i run the code it gives me 1 figure with all the circles overlapping . i want one figure with the original circle and random points ,and the other 4 are the same as figure 1 but (with the same circle and the same random points inide it  )and inside it the other circles using the given radius.

Comment: Undefined variable "rank1" or
class "rank1".

Answer (score 1):

When you want to plot on a new figure, use `figure()` to create a new figure, or, more usefully, use `figure(1)`, `figure(2)`, etc. and then you can go back to a previously opened figure using, eg: `figure(1)`, to go back to figure 1 and continue editing it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want five different figures use:
`figure(j), plot(x,y)`

```
   for j=1:4
   for i=1:50
       theta=0:.01:2*pi;
       x=radius {1,j}*cos(theta)+rank1{i,2}(1);
       y=radius {1,j}*sin(theta)+rank1{i,2}(2);
   end
   figure(j+1),plot(x,y)
   end
```

Comment: This is only going to create 4 figures. I don't where OP's 5th figure was supposed to come from though.

Comment: I noticed there is one plot outside the two for loops in the middle of the code, I think that's where the first plot comes from, but I should still update this answer. I added figure(j+1) since figure(1) was already used.